# Checkbox not getting checked after radio button change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox and two radio button.
On change event of one of the radio, I am making checked attribute of checkbox true.
It works only once.

[**`Demo`**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Uibk3uBDO5zsuYUEXCAm?p=preview)

Step to replicate it, 
1. click on ugly (checkbox is checked)
2. uncheck the checkbox
3.toggel btw ugly and good(no effect :(

Spent a lot of time on this, but couldn't figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code as follows:

1. Use [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) method instead of [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr) method to update the `checked` property.
2. Bind change event handler commonly and update the property based on selected radio button value.

```js
// or select based on the name attribute
// `$('input[type=radio][name="gender"]')`
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
  $('.xyz').prop('checked', this.value == 'bad');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="xyz"> I have a car<br>


<input type="radio" name="gender" value="good"> Good Oned<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="bad"> Ugly<br>
```

Comment: Thanks @pranav, It worked, but why do we have to bind event for every radio button, it is not the extra work for the browser? and also (just for peace of mind:) ) why my code didn't work I mean we are making it true when user select "bad "?

Comment: @92sharmasaurabh :  you are not unchecking the checkbox in your code,...... and to make it work you need to use `prop()` or `.attr('checked','checked')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this if condition .clicked radio button value is bad the clicked true are else `false` appear in checked attr .You should use [`prop()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiAkJ2DjKHUAhWItI8KHdisB6YQFggoMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fprop%2F&usg=AFQjCNGNNwd6Fkhy4Wn5nWMwXlkmGtIZGw&sig2=gQqCnTQCRkfgXHwrnFaINQ) method instead of `attr`

**updated**

> **Why not working?**
>              you selector was wrong .you have `$('input[type=radio][value = "bad"]')` .its select only value bad radio
>   button not for both .So only if you click other radio button the
>   checkbox was not unchecked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    $('.xyz').prop('checked',   $(this).val().trim() == 'bad');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" class="xyz"> I have a car<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="good"> Good Oned<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="bad"> Ugly<br><br>
```

Comment: Thanks @prasad, It worked, but why do we have to bind event for every radio button, it is not the extra work for the browser? and also (just for peace of mind :) ) why my code didn't work I mean we are making it true when user select "bad "?

Comment: Is not a extra work .Beacuse without bind a event .you cant able to find the value is bad or something else

Comment: *why my code didn't work* because you  selector was wrong .you have `$('input[type=radio][value = "bad"]')` .its select only value bad radio button not for both .So only if you click other radio button the  checkbox was not unchecked